# Подключение к MySQL из C++

Tags: c++, mysql

Добрый день.

Дали вот курсовой - база данных гостиничной системы. Знаю, что курсовой простейший. Недавно начал изучать PHP+MySQL и уже успел постичь всю красоту, удобство  MySQL. Так вот вопрос: можно ли из С++ подключаться к базам MySQL и хранить там все, извлекать и выполнять запросы из программы? На 99,9% уверен, что можно. Может приведете примерчик подключения и отправления запросов с их последующей обработкой в С++. Курсовой на MFC.

Не могу отвечать на свои вопросы. Нашел ответ (правда для С, но пойдет): [MySQL - Интерфейс для С (C API)](http://www.codenet.ru/db/mysql/mysql/c_api.php).

Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: См. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c.html Возможно потребуется скачать хедеры и библиотеки. в ubuntu это libmysqlclient-dev, как называется в виндах -- надо смотреть

Ещё ссылка: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/

Comment: Кстати, там же есть байндер для С++

Comment: Да вроде и не один. Но стоит ли их скрещивать с MFC?

Comment: Стандартный Fenstersweg -- ODBC. Скачивать из http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/. В числе достоинств -- легко заменить СУБД на другую. Или даже без СУБД (я с dbf'ками через ODBC работал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу посоветовать [Qt](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt). Немного информации по Qt + mysql тут: [QT и Базы данных](http://ru.opensuse.org/QT_%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).
[Подержать в руках](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads).

Comment: Сорри за недоописание. Курсовой по MFC. Так что QT никак(